# Get the value of selected item in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I added Item in `dropdownlist` and when I select the Item I added, it does not show up in `Label1`. Here is my code:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpOne" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

**VB**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    con.Open()
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim Sql = "SELECT College FROM College"
        cmdAdd = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, con)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        cmdAdd.Fill(ds)

        drpOne.DataSource = ds
        drpOne.DataTextField = "College"
        drpOne.DataValueField = "College"
        drpOne.DataBind()
        drpOne.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please select College", ""))
        drpOne.SelectedItem.Value = "Please select College"
        drpOne.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All", ""))
 end if
End Sub

Protected Sub drpOne_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles drpOne.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label1.Text = drpOne.SelectedItem.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i haven't checked the code, but try it this way

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    con.Open()
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim Sql = "SELECT College FROM College"
        cmdAdd = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, con)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        cmdAdd.Fill(ds)

        drpOne.AppendDataBoundItems = true
        drpOne.Add(New ListItem("Please select College", ""))//You have passed "Please select College" as text and "" as value in ListItem
        drpOne.Add(New ListItem("All", ""))

        drpOne.DataSource = ds
        drpOne.DataTextField = "College"
        drpOne.DataValueField = "College"
        drpOne.DataBind()

        drpOne.Items.FindByText("Please select College").Selected = true
 end if
End Sub

Protected Sub drpOne_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles drpOne.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label1.Text = drpOne.SelectedItem.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
drpOne.SelectedItem.Text == "enter the value which you want to search"
```

Answer (score 0):

DataValueField  must set your primary key column Id , I think CollegeId is that .

```
drpOne.DataTextField = "College"
        drpOne.DataValueField = "CollegeId"//Must set Integer value for dropdown  item vale
```